# CollectionAssert information

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, assert

When CollectionAsser.AreEqual detects differences in the elements from two collections it shows such Information as Exception message:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)
at 
filename
```

Is there any way to extend the Information so that the two elements at the position (expected and obtained) are shown, as I was comparing two variables or objects with Asser.AreEquals?

Comment: This function is not so much complicated, you could simply rewrite a homemade assert with all the information you want.

Comment: Would I have to rewrite all CollectionAsser.AreEqual for all different types of collections. I want to avoid it cause in the project there are lot of different type of collections, containing different types or object. Rewriting an assert for every type would cost a lot for us.
I would prefer if there is a way to configure VS test environment or just overwrite once (for example, rewriting the exception message format once if it was possible).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/ms243736.aspx I think you can write just one function using ICollection and iterate (with IEnumerator) throught objects and call ToString() on them. I don't think you need to implement for each type of collections.